# No rule to make target `node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi`, needed by `Makefile'

Tags: node.js, npm, makefile, node-modules, node-gyp

I am encountering an error whilst attempting to install the requirements for a package I am working on, it gets to `integer@2.1.0` and then fails due to an error with `node-gyp`.

- **Node Version**: 10.10.0 / 6.4.1
- **Platform**: Darwin Matts-MBP-3.local 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Fri May 24 17:36:10 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6041.0.0.111.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
- **Compiler**: `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.20.17)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

```
> integer@2.1.0 install /Users/mattcowley/WebstormProjects/MagicCap/node_modules/integer
> node-gyp rebuild

make: *** No rule to make target `../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mattcowley/WebstormProjects/MagicCap/node_modules/integer
gyp ERR! node -v v10.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mattcowley/.npm/_logs/2019-06-16T10_33_53_751Z-debug.log
```

[2019-06-16T10_33_53_751Z-debug.log](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/files/3294036/2019-06-16T10_33_53_751Z-debug.log)

Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I have also reached out and raised an issue with node-gyp but thought posting here might yield an answer sooner :)

Comment: I've also hit this problem. It should be noted that this is on macOS Catalina, the unstable beta version that has not been released to the public yet. This issue may be an issue with Catalina and its command line build toolchain, rather than Node/node-gyp.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your binding.gyp:

```
  'include_dirs': ["<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"],
```